# location of log file stored in system drive

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net in my application for logging exception.

I am not sure where is the log file will store in my system drive. Could anybody help me out?

Comment: What is your environment, what is your application language, how do you apply log4net in your application? give us more information

Comment: i am using visual studio 2015 with c# language..and then i get log4net by Nuget package Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, by default log4net will stored its log in same folder as your application (Debug folder for console application, winform... or `root` folder if it's a web application).

However, you can set config the path by yourself:

```
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:/temp/Mylog.log" />
      . . .
 </appender>
```

If you still can't find the log, it could be you initial log4net incorrectly.